# Hugo - rendering list view for a custom content type

Tags: go, hugo

We created a custom content type called "properties". Our content directory looks as follows: content/property/. We then created a single and list layout for the properties in our theme: themes/theme_name/layouts/property/.

Single works fine. We can't get the list layout to work at all. What template functions do we need to iterate over our properties in a list view? In single.html we use `{{range .Data.Properties }}` and `{{ range .Data.Page }}`, we also tried this in list.html. Basically, we just need to know how to iterate over data from markdown files for a specific content type on a page.

Comment: Have you tried deleting `list.html`, Hugo should produce a default list for your custom type? I would also try `{{range .Data.Property }}` (ie, singular), just to be sure. Reference is at http://gohugo.io/templates/list/

Answer (score 0):

Modifying **layouts/_default/single.html** won't work. You need to customize the **layout/_default/list.html**. Try the following code in it.

```html
{{ range .Site.RegularPages.ByDate.Reverse }}
     <h4>{{ .Title }}</h4>
     <p>{{ .Summary }}</p>
     <div> {{ .otherVariables }} </div>
{{ end }}
```

Since you are using a custom content-type called properties, you should put this in **layouts/properties/list.html**.